# FreeTTS mbrola not able to find path

Tags: java, freetts, mbrola

When I try to use the FreeTTS library I get the error:

```
Could not validate any MBROLA voices at

Some/Location/That/IThought/Held/mbrola

Make sure you FULLY specify the path to
the MBROLA directory using the mbrola.base
system property.
```

I'm using `System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "Path/here");` to set `mbrola.base` but I have no idea how to point to the path or set up mbrola. Here's my project setup, I'm using processing.

```
+SketchBook
++AI
+++Src.pde
+++data
++libraries
+++freetts-1.2
++++lib
+++++mbrola
++++mbrola
+++++mbrola
```

I'm running windows 8 so idk if that has any effect..

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, after installing MBROLA [FreeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php) ran on my Windows 8 box.

**Download MBROLA Files**

If you haven't already you will need to download 2 binary and 3 voice zips from [MBROLA](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola.html):

- PC/Windows
- PC/DOS
- us1: American English Female
- us2: American English Male
- us3: American English Male

Then follow the [Setting up MBROLA for FreeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/mbrola/README.html) guide.

**Setup MBROLA Voices**

Unzip the mbr301d files and copy the folders us1, us2 & us3 into the unzipped mbr301d folder:

```
Directory of C:\Users\Phil\Downloads\mbr301d

[mbr302a]    
mbrola.exe   
readme.txt
[us1]        
[us2]        
[us3]
```

**Test MBROLA Voices**

Test the MBROLA voices from the command prompt:

```
cd C:\Users\Phil\Downloads\freetts-1.2.2-bin\freetts-1.2
java -Dmbrola.base="C:\Users\Phil\Downloads\mbr301d" -jar lib/mbrola.jar
```

You should see a description of each voice, e.g:

```
Name: mbrola_us1
Description: MBROLA Voice us1
Organization: mbrola
Domain: general
Locale: en_US
Style: standard
Gender: FEMALE
Age: YOUNGER_ADULT
Pitch: 180.0
Pitch Range: 22.0
Pitch Shift: 1.0
Rate: 150.0
Volume: 1.0
```

**Test FreeTTS Synthesis**

At the command prompt run:

```
java -Dmbrola.base="C:\Users\Phil\Downloads\mbr301d" -jar lib/freetts.jar -voice kevin16 -dumpAudio 42.wav -text forty two
42.wav
```

Comment: this work weel . I had spend many time to make fr voices to work but it dont

Comment: where do you know it's kevin16...? how about other language who should i write?

Comment: @gumuruh the parameters including voices are described in the documentation here https://freetts.sourceforge.io/#test_program

Comment: thanks @PhillipTrelford,... i never notice that one.