# How to change voice in FreeTTS - Java

Tags: java, netbeans, freetts, mbrola

I am running a program in java in which i use FreeTTS Voices, what i want is to change the voice. 
when i run the program it shows:

> "System property "mbrola.base" is undefined.  Will not use MBROLA
>   voices."

I use the following code to speak up the text i want

```
Voice voice;
voice = voiceManager.getVoice(VOICENAME);
voice.allocate();
```

and then

```
voice.speak(t4.getText());
```

I tried to find tutorials to insert MBROLA voices. One of the tutorial i found was on their web page: http://freetts.sourceforge.net/mbrola/README.html but i am in windows not don't know anything of MAC therefore i am unable to know how to do it. Other tutorials were on Linux and i therefore even don't understand them. I am using netbeans on windows and i want someone to clearly explain me how to do this. I am a newbie and 14 year old.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the link you submitted, there's a big message that says: "NOTE: FreeTTS support for MBROLA on the Windows platform has been troublesome in the past, but appears to have been fixed by the MBROLA team. Please refer to the FreeTTS Forum for more information."

Here's a direct link to the forums: http://sourceforge.net/p/freetts/discussion/137669/thread/848a09ab

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: OK good to know. I'm still learning the protocol for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the path to the mbrola folder, either by properties or directly via the code:

```
System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "c:/.../mbrola");
```

For more see e.g. [FreeTTS mbrola not able to find path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810052/freetts-mbrola-not-able-to-find-path)